# Source files in Release, header files in Debug

Tags: c++, debugging, header

We appear to have developed a strange situation in our application.  An ASSERT is being triggered which should only run if _DEBUG is defined, but it is being evaluated when the application is compiled in Release mode.

ASSERT is defined in a header file, and is being triggered from another header file, which is included into a source file.

On further inspection, the source file is indeed running in Release mode (_DEBUG is not defined, and NDEBUG is).  However, the header files have _DEBUG defined, and not NDEBUG.

According to conventional wisdom, #including a header file is equal to cutting-and-pasting the lines of code into the source file.  This would make the above behaviour impossible.

We are compiling a large, mixed language (Intel FORTRAN and C++) application in VS2010.  This problem also occurs on our build server, though, so it doesn't seem to be just a VS2010 'feature'.

We have checked:

1. All projects are building in Release.
2. The affected cpp files do not have any unusual properties being set.
3. There are no files in our solution manually defining or undefining _DEBUG or NDEBUG.
4. We have established the above behaviour by including clauses such as:

`bool is_debug = false;`

`#ifdef _DEBUG`

`is_debug = true`

`#endif`

and breaking on the point immediately afterwards.

We are running out of things to test - about the only things that I can even hypothesise are:

1. Some standard library or external include is redefining _DEGUG and NDEBUG, or
2. Something has overridden the #include macro (is this possible?).

EDIT ----------------------------------------------------------

Thanks in part to the #error trick (below), we've found the immediate problem: In several of the projects the NDEBUG and _DEBUG are no longer defined.  All of these project were meant to have inherited *something* from the macro $(PreprocessorDefinitions) - but this is not defined anywhere.

This still leaves some awkward questions:

1. The source file that was causing the above behaviour *does* have NDEBUG defined in its project settings, and yet the header files they include don't (although VS2010 does grey-out the correct #ifdef blocks).
2. If the PreprocessorDefinitions macro is inherited by all C++ projects (which it appears to be), then why isn't it defined anywhere?

Comment: Did you try F12 with cursor on _DEBUG? (Going to the definition of the symbol.)

Comment: Nice tip, but in this case it can't find the definition :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the problem turns out to be because NDEBUG and _DEBUG are missing from the Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor->Preprocessor Definitions on several projects. Whether they were always missing, or whether they had originally been included via the $(PreprocessorDefinitions) macro is unclear.

Thanks to @Lamza, @Devolus and @Werner Henze - all of their input was useful, and the eventual problem was depressingly mundane.

Answer (score 2):

My usual approach to problems like this is, to look where the symbol is defined or an `#ifdef` is used and then put `#error Some text´ in it. This way already the compilation process will break, instead of having to wait and run it. Then you can see what really is defined.

You could also add such an #ifdef - #error combination right where the assert occurs, then you can be absolutely sure what the compiler thinks should be valid.

Comment: Thanks @Devolus - we haven't solved the problem, but this trick has given us more evidence.  It looks as though every include of that header file is somehow being included with NDEBUG not defined.

Answer (score 0):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9sb57dw4(v=vs.71).aspx:

> The assert routine is available in both the release and debug versions of the C run-time libraries. Two other assertion macros, _ASSERT and _ASSERTE, are also available, but they only evaluate the expressions passed to them when the _DEBUG flag has been defined.

In other words: either use _ASSERT(...) or #define NDEBUG, so you don't get asserts in Release builds.

Comment: Sorry: I should have been clearer.  We are defining ASSERT in one of our header files, setting it to a null function if NDEBUG is defined, and a real function if it isn't.